# How to change the color of an svg menu icon

Tags: html, css, svg, colors

I saw the following code as the menu icon used in [WhatsApp](http://whatsapp.com) website:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="icon-menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="37" height="37"
             viewBox="0 0 37 37" style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 37;" space="preserve">
            <path class="_2y-e" d="M8,26h21v-1.8H8V26z M8,11v1.8h21V11H8z
                M8,19.2h21v-1.8H8V19.2z"></path>
        </svg>
```

However, there it is in white color (change the size of window till it appears), but when I used it in my html file it is black, and changing the style color doesn't change the color of it. How can I have it in white?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fill` for the style of the icon.

```
<svg style="fill: white" version="1.1" id="icon-menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="37" height="37"
             viewBox="0 0 37 37" style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 37;" space="preserve">
            <path class="_2y-e" d="M8,26h21v-1.8H8V26z M8,11v1.8h21V11H8z
                M8,19.2h21v-1.8H8V19.2z"></path>
        </svg>
```